# What is an example of module of length $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Krull dimension takes arbitrary natural numbers, for example, if we need krull dimension $n$ ring, $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ ($k$ is a field) is an example.

But what about the length of a module?

If we want length $n$ (natural number) module, what is an example of length $n$ ($n$ is natural number) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k^n$ is a module over the field $k$ of length $n$. More generally, if $M_1,\dots,M_n$ are all simple modules (distinct or not) over $R$, then $M_1\oplus\cdots\oplus M_n$ is an $R$-module of length $n$.

Comment: Oh,I felt like the scales fell from my eyes, thank you. Could you tell me the length of Z×Z×Z ?

Comment: Is $Z$ a simple $Z$-module?

Comment: Yes Z is a simple Z-module.